# Getting null when passing QueryParameter in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, null, maui

I have two pages that shows some data in the form of list in CollectionView. One page - `ExploreCountriesPage` - is the "master" page, while the other one - `ExploreRadiosPage` - is the subpage.
I'm passing data from one ViewModel to another ViewModel. What I want is to populate the data in `ExploreRadiosPage`, but in order to do that I need to pass some data. So, I'm passing SelectedItem, which then becomes SelectedCountry in second page.

Basically I want to process the data that I got from query, but **I'm getting null in place of where the actual passed value should be**, even though that value in XAML is somehow not null and is correctly showing in the UI. I implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` which should notify when value is changing, but it does not take an effect.

```cs
public class ExploreCountriesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private NameAndCount selectedItem;
        public NameAndCount SelectedItem
        {
            get => selectedItem;
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        ...

        public ICommand NavigateTo => new Command(() => {
            var navParam = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"SelectedCountry", SelectedItem }
            };
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ExploreRadiosPage)}", navParam);
        });

        ...
    }
```

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(SelectedCountry), "SelectedCountry")]
public class ExploreRadiosViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private readonly IRadioBrowserClient radioBrowserClient;
    private NameAndCount selectedCountry;
    private List<StationInfo> stations;
    public List<StationInfo> Stations
    {
        get => stations;
        set
        {
            stations = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public NameAndCount SelectedCountry //<---- Getting null even though the value is passed from QueryParameter
    {
        get => selectedCountry;
        set
        {
            selectedCountry = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ExploreRadiosViewModel(IRadioBrowserClient radioBrowserClient)
    {
        this.radioBrowserClient = radioBrowserClient;

        InitializeData();
    }

    private async Task InitializeData()
    {
        try
        {
            Stations = await radioBrowserClient.Search.AdvancedAsync(new AdvancedSearchOptions
            {
                Country = SelectedCountry.Name. // <---- Getting null in SelectedCountry!
            });
            foreach (var result in Stations)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(result.Name);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Rad.io.Client.MAUI.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Rad.io.Client.MAUI.Pages.ExploreRadiosPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:ExploreRadiosViewModel"
             xmlns:radios="clr-namespace:RadioBrowser.Models;assembly=RadioBrowser"
             Title="{Binding SelectedCountry.Name}"> <------ It shows name of Country correctly
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto">
        <Entry Grid.Row="0" Placeholder="Search"/>
        <CollectionView x:Name="RadiosList" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
            ...
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You are getting a null in a method called from the constructor, because the constructor fires before any property values are set

Comment: Why values aren't set? Shouldn't values be already assigned when passing data from the query? How can I set them before constructor fires?

Comment: Nothing runs before the constructor.  It’s what creates the object

Comment: How can I create the `SelectedCountry` object that has the data from Query then?

Comment: if you need parameters to be used in the constructor, they need to be passed explicitly as arguments to the constructor.  Otherwise you need to wait until after the properties are set.